# How can I use `--lines` `--row` modifiers in `ps` command

Tags: ps

I often used the following command,

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,pcpu,pmem --sort=-pcpu | head
```

But in the `man` page I saw the following to output modifiers,

```
   --lines n
          Set screen height.
   --rows n
          Set screen height.
```

As if these modifiers can limit row height then I don't have to use any kind of piping which gives me a bit comfort on writing scripts with python subprocess.

But I have no idea how can I use them. As I have already tried adding them at the end of the command.

Answer (score 9):

The screen height doesn’t limit the total output, it determines how often the header is repeated (if requested):

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,pcpu,pmem --sort=-pcpu --lines=20 --header
```

will repeat the header every twenty lines (so you’ll get a header, nineteen lines of output, a header, etc.).